# Linking sliders in Netlogo so their cumulative value always remains 100% or less

Tags: netlogo

I looked but could not locate any Netlogo code that links a set of sliders that, as one increases in value the other sliders decrease so the total value never exceeds 100% (even though the total can be less than 100%). Has anyone ever tried this?

Thanks
Rudy

Answer (score 2):

You could implement it with something like an 'Update sliders' button, where you set the values you want for all the variables, then press the button and that calls a procedure to adjust them all so they add to no more than 100%. But sliders adjust either because the user adjusts them, or the NetLogo code says something like `set variable-name new-value` and that code is called in some way.

In practice, if I have multiple sliders that I don't want the total to exceed something, then I have a line at the start of the go procedure that checks the total and stops with a message if it's too high.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions JenB. I'll let you know of my progress.